# Unable to load shared object rlang.so when conda environment is activated

Tags: r, plotly, conda, rlang, reticulate

I'm using `R` on `Ubuntu` `20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)`.
I'm trying to use `R`'s `plotly`'s [`save_image`](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/plotly/html/save_image.html) function which enables static image exporting via the `kaleido` `python` `package`.

To this end I'm first activating `miniconda3`, then I'm launching `R`, but when trying to load the `plotly` `package` I'm getting this error:

```
> library(plotly)
Loading required package: ggplot2
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/dn/R/rlang/libs/rlang.so':
  /home/dn/R/rlang/libs/rlang.so: undefined symbol: R_ActiveBindingFunction
```

My `R` `sessionInfo` is:

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /home/dn/miniconda3/lib/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C           LC_TIME=C.UTF-8
 [4] LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C              LC_ADDRESS=C
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C         LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

If I try the same without activating `miniconda3` I am able to load `plotly`, but `save_image` gives this error:

```
Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert) :
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kaleido'

Detailed traceback:
  File "/home/dn/R/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 39, in _import_hook
    module = _import(
```

Any idea?

Comment: How and where is R installed? and why is it so old? Look like two separate installations (outside Conda and in **base**). Conda R environments are great (it's all I use), but the `defaults` channel (`main`, `r`, `anaconda`) are not reliable for this. Instead, everything should be sourced from `conda-forge` and should not be installed in the **base** environment.

Comment: I had this when running R 3.6.1 that tried to load an R-4.1.2-installed library due to a mistake in my `$R_LIBS` variable, just might help pinpoint your problem.